# Why are trees shining in background?

Tags: unity, shaders, terrain, tree

Currently I am creating a forest scene in the dark, and the trees are shining far away, but when I get close they are fine. I have the shaders set to "Nature/Tree Soft Occlusion [bark/leaves]", but they are still rendering strange far away, but close they are fine.

[image]

I tried placing the trees in a folder named "Ambient-Occlusion" like said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12110274/why-do-my-trees-shine-bright-white-in-the-background/12113805#12113805), but no luck. Also fog is turned off. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

When I looked at the trees using the "Render Paths" camera, they appeared red while everything else was green.

[image: picture]

**UPDATE 2**

I have tried re-installing the package I downloaded these from, but still no luck.

**UPDATE 3**

I have added some trees manually, and they work fine, but when adding them by painting on the terrain I get the problem.

**FINAL UPDATE**

I tried building the game to see if this had the effect on the .exe, and it didn't. So I just have to ignore when I am debugging it, as it works fine on the build. Thanks for all the help, it just seems like an error with unity. Picture of build:

[image]

Comment: Not familiar with Unity, so I'll write as comment - maybe you have Fog enabled?

Comment: No, I had that effect so I turned it off, worked fine for a while, and now it is doing it without fog turned on

Comment: So what happens if you turn fog on?

Comment: @Laurent I can see maybe a few trees farther, but they are much darker

Comment: @Kinected So maybe fog that is on-even-if-it's-off, with some weird settings?

Comment: Based on a complete guess, I'd say it's disabling shaders for far away objects.

Comment: Your images are near-black. Don't forget that people have quite varying display devices and brightness/contrast settings. If you intend for this to be a playable game that should convey an emotion other than frustration and a swift Alt-F4, consider fixing your levels.

Comment: The player will have means of light, I just didnt show images with them

Comment: It's because the trees are happier the further away from you they are.

Comment: Haha, too bad I can't say `terrain1.trees.mood == Moods.Happy;` :)

Comment: Have you tried testing this on another computer? It might be a problem with your graphics card. Supposedly, some have problems with mipmaps. I had a similar problem when I ran Unity on an older computer.

Comment: @tyjkenn I decided to build the project to see if it would effect the game, and it works fine in the .exe, just a problem with unity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out that it was rendered fine in the builds of the project, just not in the debugger in unity. I am planning on reporting this as an error on unity's site, as it was messed up in the debugger only, not the game.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the problem by adding fog with the properties:

- Color: R: 0 G: 0 B: 0 A: 255

  Mode: Exp2

  Density 0.03

I know this doesn't solve the problem, but I wanted to use fog in my game anyway and this was an easy solution. I am not going to accept this as the answer since it doesn't actually solve the question, I just wanted to say what ended up working. Picture:

[image: picture]

It also adds that scary/mysterious feel to it, which I am happy about. I would still love to have an actual answer to how to fix this.

Comment: Unity terrain trees are rendered out to textures at a given distance which is what you are seeing. You would have to dig into the shader that is used to render the billboarded textures at distance and see how it's being affected by your lighting setup.

Comment: @RubberMallet Actually Rubber Mallet has it right. The trees are shiny because they rendered without being affected by light. I think he should add an answer and get accepted.

Comment: Nice, I can't see anything on that Screenshot. It's just black. In your question I was able to see at least some trees :D

Comment: @bummzack Turn up your monitor contrast then you'll be able to see that both pictures have very dark content. However, the OP should definitely consider that not everyone has a super-bright screen like his/hers.

Comment: @Rushyo I can't since I was viewing this on an iPad. So let's just hope he doesn't plan to target iOS ;) So yeah, the OP needs to crank up the brightness or add an in-game option to adjust it. Some sort of "calibration" when the game first starts would be a clever idea.

Comment: @ArthurWulfWhite How would I do that? Edit the shader?

Comment: @Kinected - That would be one way. If I were you, I would look at the shader pass that renders the billboarded tree at distance and see what lighting it's using. The problem with using that toolkit is that it doesn't work for every scenario and probably works much better in day/evening light setups.

Comment: I can barely even see anything in that picture. You want to make it brighter.

Comment: I am going to add a brightness adjuster to the beginning of the game